# How To Open Another Activity By Swiping

Tags: android, android-activity

I am A beginner at android. I have created an app which loads news from JSON to recycler view. I want to open an activity when the user swipes from left to right. I tried different methods but it doesn't work for me. Please help.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried with some sample code?

Comment: you want to open different type of activity on **RecyclerView Items left right swipe** ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an activity first and put a view pager in it and switch between fragments : ( its better to use fragments at this kind of situations, u can swipe between ur fragments by using android view pager )

Here is a great link that gonna help you :

https://medium.com/@kyroschow/how-to-use-viewpager-for-navigating-between-fragments-with-tablayout-a28b4cf92c42

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

The better option is to use one **Activity** & other **Fragments**. And then use **Viewpager** for swipe between fragments. Follow below link:

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide